# Apache Beam TextIO wildcard on local files

Tags: apache-beam

I can't use the wildcard character "*" with TextIO and local files as the underlying library doesn't seem to support it according to the exception below. The code works fine with wildcards if I use a Google Cloud storage path. Do I need to escape wildcards in any way?

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo$1.run(ExecJavaMojo.java:293)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.nio.file.InvalidPathException: Illegal char <*> at index 36: C:\input\*
        at sun.nio.fs.WindowsPathParser.normalize(WindowsPathParser.java:182)
        at sun.nio.fs.WindowsPathParser.parse(WindowsPathParser.java:153)
        at sun.nio.fs.WindowsPathParser.parse(WindowsPathParser.java:77)
        at sun.nio.fs.WindowsPath.parse(WindowsPath.java:94)
        at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystem.getPath(WindowsFileSystem.java:255)
        at java.nio.file.Paths.get(Paths.java:84)
        at org.apache.beam.sdk.util.FileIOChannelFactory.specToFile(FileIOChannelFactory.java:81)
        at org.apache.beam.sdk.util.FileIOChannelFactory.match(FileIOChannelFactory.java:92)
        at my.package.XmlRawIO$Read$Bound.expand(XmlRawIO.java:235)
        at my.package.XmlRawIO$Read$Bound.expand(XmlRawIO.java:151)
        at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.applyInternal(Pipeline.java:475)
        at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.applyTransform(Pipeline.java:389)
        at org.apache.beam.sdk.values.PBegin.apply(PBegin.java:47)
        at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.apply(Pipeline.java:160)
        at my.package.PushEnactorTransactions.main(PushTransactions.java:70)
        ... 6 more
```

Answer (score 1):

Historically, there was an issue where support for local file system in Apache Beam didn't support pattern matching on the Windows OS. This didn't apply in any other case -- local file system on other operating systems, Google Cloud Storage on any operating system, etc. worked as expected.

There were plenty of improvements in this area recently, and there are some more in progress. I believe this specific exception was fixed, so I'd encourage to just try again with a newer version.